# SRCDS cannot connect to outside world when bound to purchased FO ip block

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, firewall, ubuntu-20.04

I purchased a dedicated server from OVH running Ubuntu 21.04 (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-31-generic x86_64), and an additional block of addresses to accompany it. I used [This Official OVH Guide](https://docs.ovh.com/us/en/dedicated/network-ipaliasing/#ubuntu-1710-and-following_1) to add these IPs to the network interface.

The Problem: When I try to bind an instance of SRCDS to any of the additional addresses, I get the following error:

`src/common/tcpconnection.cpp (1036) : Assertion Failed: Tried to initiate an outbound connection to 51.81.183.116:27024, bound to local address 51.81.183.116:26901.  An ephemeral local port should be used for outbound TCP conections!  How does this work?`

SRCDS does not appear to respond or receive incoming requests

I have disabled UFW as a testing measure, but this doesn't seem to be relevant to the issue.

SRCDS is not behind any form of reverse proxy

Things I have tried:

- setting sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 27000    60999

Comment: Wow, does it actually have an *assert* for the local port range, "just in case we know better than the OS"? That's a ... silly check for srcds to be doing.

Comment: That aside, what's your `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` set to?

Comment: @user1686 that command returns net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999